# How to center the tagline of the header toolbar in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, header

How to center the tagline of the header toolbar in wordpress?

I have tried centering the tagline at the 'Theme options' in Jupiter.

I could not center my tagline without pushing the other elements in the same line to the next line.

Comment: We'll need more information to help you. Code snippets, a link. As is, it's unlikely we can help you resolve your issue.

Comment: can you post some screenshot and code ?